# How I can count sequential na data in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I have some question when using pyspark with my data

I have data like this

| group_num | useage | days | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 20200101 | 1 |
| 1 | 10 | 20200101 | 2 |
| 1 | na | 20200101 | 3 |
| 2 | 30 | 20200102 | 1 |
| 2 | na | 20200102 | 2 |
| 2 | na | 20200102 | 3 |
| 3 | na | 20200105 | 10 |
| 3 | na | 20200105 | 11 |
| 3 | 5 | 20200105 | 12 |

---

What I want to do this data is that count sequetial na data in useage as the group.

---

| group_num | useage | days | time | na_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 20200101 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 10 | 20200101 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | na | 20200101 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 30 | 20200102 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | na | 20200102 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | na | 20200102 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | na | 20200105 | 10 | 1 |
| 3 | na | 20200105 | 11 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 | 20200105 | 12 | 0 |

---

I want to count na if the na is sequential and reset when use age have datas. And also count reset when group_num has changed.

I can do this works in python, but due to the size of the data, I have to use pyspark instead of python.

Does anyone have answers to solve this problem?

Comment: spark won't retain a sort order, so a cumulative count would require an ordering field. are there any `id` fields that can be used to order the df while counting?

Comment: Actually, data also have some time series data such as date and time. So I think if I use those date and time, I can sort field

Comment: how does that look like with these columns?

Comment: Date and time also have columns just like useage or group_num and they are both made as integer.

Comment: please add them in the question's table so that we can understand the ordering

Comment: |group_num|useage|days|time|
|--|--|--|--|
|1|10|20200101|1|
|1|10|20200101|2|
The data looks like this

Comment: i have no way to understand the ordering with just 1 row -- please add the columns in your question body.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I have changed questions data table

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with an unbounded sum window function.

```
# input df
data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls). \
    toDF(['group_num', 'usage', 'day', 'time'])

# +---------+-----+--------+----+
# |group_num|usage|     day|time|
# +---------+-----+--------+----+
# |        1|   10|20200101|   1|
# |        1|   10|20200101|   2|
# |        1|   na|20200101|   3|
# |        2|   30|20200102|   1|
# |        2|   na|20200102|   2|
# |        2|   na|20200102|   3|
# |        3|   na|20200105|  10|
# |        3|   na|20200105|  11|
# |        3|    5|20200105|  12|
# +---------+-----+--------+----+

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('sec_group', (func.col('usage') == 'na').cast('int')). \
    withColumn('na_count', 
               func.sum('sec_group').over(wd.partitionBy('group_num', 'sec_group').orderBy('day', 'time').rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0))
               ). \
    drop('sec_group'). \
    orderBy('group_num', 'day', 'time'). \
    show()

# +---------+-----+--------+----+--------+
# |group_num|usage|     day|time|na_count|
# +---------+-----+--------+----+--------+
# |        1|   10|20200101|   1|       0|
# |        1|   10|20200101|   2|       0|
# |        1|   na|20200101|   3|       1|
# |        2|   30|20200102|   1|       0|
# |        2|   na|20200102|   2|       1|
# |        2|   na|20200102|   3|       2|
# |        3|   na|20200105|  10|       1|
# |        3|   na|20200105|  11|       2|
# |        3|    5|20200105|  12|       0|
# +---------+-----+--------+----+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks! It makes me much easier to change datas.

Answer (score 0):

```
dt = [
    (1, '10', '20200101', 1),
    (1, '10', '20200101', 2),
    (1, 'na', '20200101', 3),
    (2, '30', '20200102', 1),
    (2, 'na', '20200102', 2),
    (2, 'na', '20200102', 3),
    (3, 'na', '20200105', 10),
    (3, 'na', '20200105', 11),
    (3, '5', '20200105', 12),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(dt, ['group_num', 'useage', 'days', 'time'])

df_na = (
    df.filter(" useage = 'na' ")
    .withColumn('count', row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('group_num').orderBy('time')))
    .select('group_num', 'time', 'count')
)

(
    df.join(df_na, ['group_num', 'time'], "left")
        .fillna(0)
        .sort('group_num', 'time')
        .show(100, False)
)
# +---------+----+------+--------+-----+
# |group_num|time|useage|days    |count|
# +---------+----+------+--------+-----+
# |1        |1   |10    |20200101|0    |
# |1        |2   |10    |20200101|0    |
# |1        |3   |na    |20200101|1    |
# |2        |1   |30    |20200102|0    |
# |2        |2   |na    |20200102|1    |
# |2        |3   |na    |20200102|2    |
# |3        |10  |na    |20200105|1    |
# |3        |11  |na    |20200105|2    |
# |3        |12  |5     |20200105|0    |
# +---------+----+------+--------+-----+
```